# missing packages in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, bitbucket-pipelines, yarn-v2

Hy everyone. I'm trying to make a pipeline for my nextjs-project and got some problem

I have especial function for generate buildId

```
# scripts/generate-build-id.js

const nextBuildId = require('next-build-id')
const path = require('path');

const generateBuildId = async () => {
    const isDev = [process.env.APP_ENV, process.env.NODE_ENV].some(setting => setting && setting !== 'production');
    return nextBuildId({ dir: path.join(__dirname, '..') })
        .then(BUILD_ID => `${isDev ? 'dev' : 'prod'}_${BUILD_ID}`);
}

module.exports = { generateBuildId };
```

And I use it in my next-config

```
# next.config.js
const { generateBuildId } = require('./scripts/generate-build-id');

module.exports = {
  ...
  generateBuildId: async () => generateBuildId(),
  ...
};
```

Everything is Ok. Project works fine, builds fine and etc.

But If I try to deploy my project using bitbucket's pipeline I get errors:

Really easy pipeline-config

```
image: node:18

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install dependencies
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - yarn install
    - step:
        name: Build
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - yarn build
```

But build step returns an error

```
 + yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$                        yarn clear
$ rm -rf .next
$       next build
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
> Build error occurred
Error: Cannot find module 'next-build-id'
Require stack:
 + /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/scripts/generate-build-id.js
```

And of course this package is including into my package.json. It installing well locally but not on the bitbucket's machine

I have no idea why it happens
I tried a lot of combinations of npm instal, yarn install. Tried to add `yarn add next-build-id` to install packages step but anyway this error happens

Answer (score 0):

It was really stupid mistake: I just needed to clear node-cache in pipeline

[image]